# access of undefined property - Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, actionscript

Flex 4.6 Mobile Application

I am getting the error "access to undefined property PrepForDisplay"

In my Declarations tag I have

```
 <s:CurrencyFormatter id="PrepForDisplay"
     currencySymbol="" 
     useCurrencySymbol="true"
     negativeCurrencyFormat="0"
     positiveCurrencyFormat="0"/>
```

In my MXML section I have

```
<s:List id="lst" dataProvider="{dp}" useVirtualLayout="true" width="100%" height="95%" top="30" alternatingItemColors="[#66FFFF, #33CCCC]">
<s:itemRenderer>
<fx:Component>
       <s:ItemRenderer>
    <s:HGroup  gap="10">
    <s:Label text="{data.Period}" />
    **<s:Label text="{PrepForDisplay.format(data.Payment)}" />**
    </s:HGroup>
  </s:ItemRenderer>
</fx:Component>
```

The error occurs on the bold line.
If I change it to Number(data.Payment).toFixed(2)  everything works fine.
I have used the currencyFormatter the way I have it on other views with success.  I can even use it on this view in a function but when I try to apply it in the label I get the error.

Any ideas?

cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is, that its a scoping error, on other words the formatter gets created in the scope of the component, that creates the list, and the itemrenderer gets instantiated be the list. So it does not know of a variable (PrepForDisplay), that is referenced inside the itemrenderer.

To solve it, simply move the CurrencyFormatter tag inside the itemrenderer:

```
<s:ItemRenderer>
<fx:Declarations>
<s:CurrencyFormatter id="PrepForDisplay"
 currencySymbol="" 
 useCurrencySymbol="true"
 negativeCurrencyFormat="0"
 positiveCurrencyFormat="0"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:HGroup  gap="10">
    <s:Label text="{data.Period}" />
    <s:Label text="{PrepForDisplay.format(data.Payment)}" />
</s:HGroup>
```

Or simply define the itemrenderer in a separate file.

Comment: Thank you sydd that worked perfectly. I don't know why but it did. I am very new to Flex and I am having a hard time following the Adobe documentation.  Again I thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: The reason it works is that when you specify an item renderer like that (wrapping it in a `<fx:Component>` tag, also called an inline item renderer), you're actually creating a separate class that is not part of the parent class. So by moving the declaration inside the item renderer, you've made that currency formatter accessible to the renderer.  Note, there is a significant difference in what is happening, after you made that change: Originally you had only 1 `CurrencyFormatter` object, now you have 1 formatter for each item renderer :)